# Converting a string (e.g. "202309101010") into a date object

Tags: typescript

I have a string in the format "YYYYMMDDHHMM" (e.g. "202309101010") representing a date and time. I want to convert this string into a `Date` object in TypeScript.

I'm using the following code to achieve this conversion:

```
const dateString: string = "202309101010"; 
const year: number = parseInt(dateString.substring(0, 4), 10); 
const month: number = parseInt(dateString.substring(4, 6), 10); 
const day: number = parseInt(dateString.substring(6, 8), 10); 
const hour: number = parseInt(dateString.substring(8, 10), 10); 
const minute: number = parseInt(dateString.substring(10, 12), 10); 

const formattedDate: Date = new Date(year, month - 1, day, hour, minute); 
console.log(formattedDate);
```

While this works fine, I'm wondering if there's a more elegant or efficient way to achieve the same result. Are there any built-in TypeScript or JavaScript functions that could simplify this process? Or any other methods that could handle this conversion more gracefully?

Comment: You can use `moment.js` https://momentjs.com/guides/#/parsing/strict-mode/

Comment: @Behemoth the question is a common one and many answers can be found in google and stackoverflow, whoever downvoted probably thought that but didn't bother giving an explanation

Comment: @Daviid thank you, but in my case i can't use moment.js do you know any other native handling of TS?

Comment: check answer with @Lehks suggestion or check https://momentjs.com/docs/#/-project-status/recommendations/ for recommended alternatives

Comment: @Daviid no I don't want to be dependent on specific libraries to do a conversion like this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[The ECMAScript spec](https://tc39.es/ecma262/multipage/numbers-and-dates.html#sec-date.parse) describes the method for constructing a `Date` object from a string like this:

> The function first attempts to parse the String according to the format described in Date Time String Format ([21.4.1.32](https://tc39.es/ecma262/multipage/numbers-and-dates.html#sec-date-time-string-format)), including expanded years. If the String does not conform to that format the function may fall back to any implementation-specific heuristics or implementation-specific date formats. Strings that are unrecognizable or contain out-of-bounds format element values shall cause this function to return **NaN**.

That "Date Time String Format" it describes is of the form **YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss.sssZ**, which does not match the string format you are using. So if you want to construct a `Date` object from it with well-defined behaviour, then you are doing the right thing by first extracting its constituent parts and then passing them into the `Date` constructor as separate arguments.

As to how best to extract them, what you're doing now works just fine. There's no need to change it if it's not causing a problem.

That said, a ready alternative that comes to mind would be to use a regular expression, since that could both confirm that your string has the correct format and extract its parts (as strings, not numbers) in one call of [`match`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match):

```js
function toDate(dateString: string): Date {
    const dateStringPattern = /^(\d{4})(\d{2})(\d{2})(\d{2})(\d{2})$/;

    const [match, ...parts] = dateString.match(dateStringPattern) ?? [];
    if (!match) {
        // Handle this error somehow
        throw new Error(`Incorrectly formatted string: '${dateString}'`)
    }

    const [year, month, day, hour, minute] = parts.map((part) => parseInt(part, 10));
    const formattedDate: Date = new Date(year, month - 1, day, hour, minute); 
    return formattedDate;
}

console.log(toDate('202309101010'));
try {
    console.log(toDate('abc')); // Throws an error
} catch (e) {
    console.error(e);
}
```

[TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=17&ssc=51&pln=7&pc=73#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABFOARAhlApgCgCaZYDKUATjGAOYBciAzmRZQJS0baIDeAUIn4hAQNEBbCXJUACpmykkAXkQB6AHo4AOnk4AWAL7MNWgEz7DnEwc3nTViwBIlAbm69+gsMIDaAW0wQAFgA0iAB0YQAO6KRQdAC6iIqixIxUIb5QAfiE4kzSULJgzIgA-MWInrHO-IgwwIg4AITpAUU81dVKSogAEuhgeAA2WMj+MHSIWKSkcKT0cN5Y-nAA7q7tI9PLiGBYWwCiUzM4AAYAkpAzpFjQAwCeiMAz6dh49Ck0iADkdpxJOVS6T7HZhrRC6FzVdxeW5YKLBbwIKBBEToW7BJYgUjwiggbDxRSRaJ0NLocI4HCEqBFeQAPkQhLoWHOUApUSgwQAjAAGZjMKpuIRQB5PGRYPDsLBsQgJba7RASnAwuGIBFgJGIAC0iA5wQIaMQGKxKpx2D5iFBVygmKQj1IzzFEuc4O4ULgQxCAzglBwKAVnyMXKMAGYuQBObkRrmfXnOMj3NoCjxurAer0+tCEHCfdAAIwg0bNnUQABV-Jtxn0JodSNxdAI-P56lhWqDXe7JtNSDhm07uEA)

Comment: Thank you this is good solution to make safe the date-convert through the constructor.

Answer (score -2):

You could use `moment.js` and parse the string like so:

```js
moment('202309101010', 'YYYYMMDDhhmmss').format()
```

Or

`date-fns`
https://date-fns.org/v2.30.0/docs/parse#usage

```js
var parse = require('date-fns/parse') // CommonJS
import parse from 'date-fns/parse' // ES 2015
import { parse } from 'date-fns' // ESM

parse('202309101010', 'YYYYMMDDhhmmss')
```

Comment: https://momentjs.com/docs/#/-project-status/

Comment: [https://date-fns.org/](https://date-fns.org/) would be the better alternative to the deprecated moment.js.

Comment: Technically not deprecated, just finished development. It still works just fine.

Comment: yes, it isn't deprecated, but I don't want to be dependent on specific libraries, i prefer a safe method in TS, but more elegant then mine.